# Firebase: “Error loading the Firebase SDK, check the console.”

Tags: firebase

I'm currently using firebase to host my app. I've been able to successfully deploy the webapp, however none of the HTML, CSS, or JavaScript features have loaded. Additionally, when the URL opens, I'm prompted with the following:

[image]

How can I avoid this Firebase SDK error message from persisting and deploy my HTML, CSS, JavaScript code?

All help here is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you might have initialized your firebase project in empty directory so first  check your directory for html files and make sure it includes all the firebase cdn imports

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. For me, I thought that it was something related to caching so I just cleared my cached and it worked.